# Scrollbars appears on my page when jquery dialogs open

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

When I open a jquery dialog, **scrollbars appears on my page**. I don't know why because my jquery dialogs are pretty small. And when I move my dialog (by dragging with the title bar), immediatly scrollbars disappears.

Any idea?

Thanks.

---

EDIT

I debug a little more and I am able to reproduce the problem. On my page, I have kind of tabs (loaded with ajax). The first one need scrollbars on the page. When I click on the second 'tab', no scrollbars appears BUT on this page, when I open a dialog jQuery scrollbars come back !? If I drag a little the jQuery dialog (with the title bar) the scrollbars dissapears and don't come back if I open again the jQuery dialog. It works until I come back on the first 'tab' which need scrollbars.

I don't know if I'm clear.

---

EDIT 2

Ok guys, I tested much and I point more clearly where the problems was. Here it is: When user click on header menu (ajax links) a temporary jquery dialog is showed to ask user to wait... until the page is loaded. This jquery dialog is modal >> a gray background is showed on the entire window height/width.

[image]

As you can see on the capture above, the height is considerable. Navigating from page A (long page) to page B (short page). At this time, the dialog modal is closed. On the newly showed page (which is much smaller), I click on a button to show another jquery modal dialog. It seems that jquery is still thinking that my page has an height of 1198px but it is not the case!! And thus I see scrollbars appears.

Now the big question is: **what do I have to do to avoid this behaviour?**

Comment: Always? With some specific browser? If you're using ASP.NET you may need to reparent your dialogs.

Comment: @Adriano, Ben: I updated my question.

Comment: Code? Markup? Help us help you.

Comment: @Adriano, Jay, Ben, Charlietfl: I updated my question (EDIT 2) with much more infos.

Comment: resizable: false,                
                open: function(event, ui){$('body').css('overflow','hidden');$('.ui-widget-overlay').css('width','100%'); }, 
                close: function(event, ui){$('body').css('overflow','auto'); } -- Are you looking for this?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution:

```
$('.ui-widget-overlay').css('height', '100%');

$("#dialog-modal").dialog('close');
```

Before closing my jquery modal dialog (saying Please wait...) I adjust the height of the gray background (typically when using jquery modal). This way, next jquery modal will not do scrollbars appears.

Keep in mind the followinf scenario:

- Page A is showed (long page)
- user click on a link to navigate (ajax call >> partial) to Page B
- modal jquery dialog (*) is showed to ask user to wait...
- Page B is loaded (short page)
- modal jquery dialog (*) is closed

The difference of height between page A and page B was the problem !!

Answer (score -2):

I don't have much time to answer right now, but one thing I was thinking was just to permanently add vertical scroll bars within the html tag of CSS, just to see if that initially gets rid of the problem.

Comment: @charlietfl I'm unable to post comments below the question, so I didn't really have a choice.

Comment: how can I use the site properly when it doesn't allow me to comment in the question area. someone's grumpy, go back to bed and wake up on your good side, if you have one.